# GPars, GORM, Batch Upload

Tags: multithreading, grails, grails-orm, gpars

I have a process that needs to build a PDF document and combine it with 100s of other documents being created.

I want to multiple thread this.  Where I pass into the Service a list of events that I need the PDF generated and saved to the DB.  The document is saved too a destination and the path is saved to the DB.

So I am using GPars with 10 threads.  I am running into an issue where, when I lazy fetch off of the Event I get an error message

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   com.srm.billing.DepositNotice.depositNoticeRevisions,  no
>   session or session was closed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:  failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   com.srm.billing.DepositNotice.depositNoticeRevisions,  no
>   session or session was closed

I notice several sites are saying Hibernate is not thread safe which is I think is causing the problem.

```
GParsPool.withPool( poolSize ) { forkJoinPool ->
            depositNotices = pEvents.collectParallel{ event -> 
                Event.withNewSession{ session ->
                    return buildDepositNotice( event )
                    session.flush()
                } 
            }
        }

byte[] findlDocument = null
        finalDocument = pdfUtilService.concatPDFs( depositNotices )
```

The results I am seeing is that when this error occurs then what was processed events earlier are committed to the DB and that is an issue.

My end goal is the List of events passed into the method is completed as a single batch, where if 1 fails no record is committed to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `collectParallel()` is intended to be used with code that is side-effect free. But you may still be able to use it, with caution.

Assuming `buildDepositNotice(Event)` returns a saved domain instance, when that instance is used outside of the `Event.withNewSession(Closure)` closure it will be *detached*. While the instance is detached you can access it's properties and such, but to persist it you'd have to reattach it to the current session first.

To collect the deposit notices, make sure the instance is the last expression evaluated in the `withNewSession()` closure.

```
Event.withNewSession{ session ->
    def depositNotice = buildDepositNotice(event)

    session.flush()
    depositNotice
}
```

And if `pdfUtilService.concatPDFs()` needs to persist deposit notices, then make sure it's calling `attach()` on the deposit notice first.

Comment: Inside the buildDepositNotice, I get that error while attempting to build deposit notice, what I have found I had to do is instead of going **event.depositNotices[0]** which will through the above exception.  I have to use **List<DepositNotice> depositNotices = DepositNotice.findByEvent(event)**  which seems to be acceptable and attached to the hibernate session.   It seems strange getting by first level is acceptable, but getting as a child breaks hibernate.